# How to refactor the ternary operator code using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am getting the color based on the variable books and pens. if books or pens value is 0 apply red, value is 1 apply blue else green.

From code below the code is redunant meaning i am applying same colors based on value. how can i refactor it such that it can be be simplified further.

Below is the code,

```
const booksCountColor =
    books === 0
        ? red
        : books === 1
        ? blue
        : green;
const pensCountColor =
    pens === 0
        ? red
        : pens === 1
        ? blue
        : green;
```

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Will the count be 2 in case of green?

Comment: anything above 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested conditionals are awful for readability. I'd make an array instead, and alternate with `green`:

```
const colors = [red, blue];
const booksCountColor = colors[books] || green;
const pensCountColor = colors[pens] || green;
```

You could make it a bit DRY-er by putting it into a function

```
const colors = [red, blue];
const getColor = index => colors[index] || green;
const booksCountColor = getColor(books);
const pensCountColor = getColor(pens);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with nested ternary statements/if else statements is that it can be rather messy. You can consider rewriting it by using the early return pattern to keep things clean.

```
const booksCountColor = () => {
  if (books === 0) {
    return red;
  }

  if (books === 1) {
    return blue;
  }

  return green;
};

const pensCountColor = () => {
  if (pens === 0) {
    return red;
  }

  if (pens === 1) {
    return blue;
  }

  return green;
};
```

Comment: true this is easy to read...but we have a pattern to use only ternary when possible.

Comment: Questionable pattern imo, ternary is fine for short non nested conditions, but it gets messy quickly.

Comment: single-layered ternary and if else statements are fine. The only issue is when you start nesting them. nested ternary operators is actually one of the rules stated in eslint (https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary)